# Como posso substituir uma parte de uma string por ela mesma mais o caractere "~"?

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex, replace

Como posso substituir uma parte de uma *string* por ela mesma mais o caractere "~"?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma: só que quando a *string* tem dois números iguais como o 51 que vem logo após AP e o contido no 17**51**3322  o `Replace` faz a troca nos dois locais sendo que só quero que faça o `Replace` no número completo.

Minha *string* deveria ficar da seguinte forma:

> RUASANTA HELENA, 769~ AP 51~ BL H JD ALVORADA~ 17513322~

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string lista = "RUASANTA HELENA, 769  AP 51 BL H JD ALVORADA~ 17513322 ";

        var match = Regex.Match(lista, "[0-9]+");
        while (match.Success)
        {
            lista = lista.Replace(match.Value, match.Value + "~");
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        System.Console.Write(lista);    
    }       
}
```

Comment: Assim também deve funcionar: http://ideone.com/59v7or

Comment: @stderr, obrigado também funcionar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Se o número completo sempre for seguido de um espaço, você pode usar o *pattern* "`([0-9]+?)`" e substituir pelo match que ocorreu dentro dos parênteses mais o `~` e um espaço(que deu match também):

```
string lista = "RUASANTA HELENA, 769  AP 51 BL H JD ALVORADA~ 17513322 ";
lista = Regex.Replace(lista, "([0-9]) ", "$1~ ");
```

[Exemplo no DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YMlwlT)

Comment: Use `\d` jovem, `[0-9]` é feio :D

Answer (score 7):

A pergunta cita RegEx e a resposta aceita deu uma boa solução. Eu prefiro fazer manualmente porque eu faço isso mais fácil do que eu faria com RegEx, mas sei que não é o caso de todo mundo. Se a performance for importante o RegEx nem sempre é uma boa opção. Quase todos algoritmos é possível fazer mais rápido se produzir manualmente. Foi o que eu fiz:

```
public static string MudaEndereco(string texto, char adicao = '~') {
    var resultado = new StringBuilder(texto.Length * 2);
    var anterior = '\0';
    foreach (var caractere in texto) {
        if (Char.IsDigit(anterior) && Char.IsWhiteSpace(caractere)) {
            resultado.Append(adicao);
        }
        resultado.Append(caractere);
        anterior = caractere;
    }
    return resultado.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/35VTUl). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GveDLi). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Replace2.cs).

O RegEx perdeu para o algoritmo manual em média de pelo menos por 4X. Teve casos de dezenas que eu desconsiderei, talvez por causa de coleta de lixo. 4X não é pouca coisa. Dependendo da máquina a diferença ficou em 6X ou mais. Não entendo tanto de RegEx, posso ter feito alguma coisa errada, mas fiz em cima do que foi respondido. Tentei algumas otimizações que o RegEx do .Net permite e só piorou :).

Eu usei até um critério que pode ter deixado mais lento porque eu não peguei só uma caractere branco, peguei qualquer caractere que seja considerado um branco, se o requisito não permite isso é só mudar para um simples `' '`. A verificação de dígitos também está feita de forma que funciona onde os números estão representados de forma não comum na tabela Unicode, isso certamente também deixa mais lento.

Eu fiz um exemplo extra mais personalizável e o resultado foi praticamente o mesmo.

Note que eu dei uma otimizada no padrão do RegEx, o `?` não fazia sentido ali e poderia usar `\d`. Então eu faria:

```
Regex.Replace(lista, "(\\d+) ", "$1~ ")
```

Então se a resposta tiver que ser RegEx este seria meu código.

Answer (score 4):

[**Método String.Replace (String, String)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retorna uma nova seqüência na qual todas as ocorrências de uma String
>   especificada são substituídas por outra String especificada.

#### Sintaxe

```
public string Replace(
    string oldValue,
    string newValue
)
```

#### Exemplo

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String s = "aaa";
      Console.WriteLine("The initial string: '{0}'", s);
      s = s.Replace("a", a+"~");
      Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", s);
   }
}
```

**[Método String.Concat (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Concatena duas instâncias de String especificadas.

#### Sintaxe

```
public static string Concat(
    string str0,
    string str1
)
```

#### Exemplo

```
string str0 = "teste";
string str1 = "~";

str0 = string.Concat(str0, str1)
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Com o String.Replace() eu precisaria saber o index de inicio e fim da string para pegar a parte especificar da string e fazer o replace. isso é complicado quando envolve muita informação em uma string a resposta do Daniel resolveu.